# How do I get the author of a discord command in c#

Tags: c#, discord.net

I need to get a message's author, but don't know how.

I plan to get it kinda this way

```
public async Task Command(CommandContext context, [Here i would get the sender name] user)
```

Comment: What API are you using? Is it this one? https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus/

Comment: OR this one? https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are getting the command but if you are looking at an iMessage, it has an Author:

https://discord.foxbot.me/stable/api/Discord.IMessage.html#Discord_IMessage_Author

That author is an `iUser` who has a `Username` property:

https://discord.foxbot.me/stable/api/Discord.IUser.html

Which might look like:

`command.Author.Username`